# Documentation links not working in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

All links in help files are not working for me in RStudio. For instance, if I click on the `to.period` link below:

[image]

I get the error:

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this and know of a fix?

**Session Info**

Note that `xUtils_1.0` and `QServer_1.0` are my own packages. I don't believe them to be the problem because I've used them with no problems for many months now.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] tcltk     grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] cairoDevice_2.20     tcltk2_1.2-10        gWidgets2RGtk2_1.0-2 RGtk2_2.20.29        memoise_0.2.1       
 [6] gWidgets2_1.0-5      digest_0.6.4         scales_0.2.4         gridExtra_0.9.1      lubridate_1.3.3     
[11] data.table_1.9.2     devtools_1.5         xUtils_1.0           QServer_1.0          stringr_0.6.2       
[16] zoo_1.7-11           ggplot2_1.0.0        RSQLite_0.11.4       DBI_0.2-7           

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] codetools_0.2-8  colorspace_1.2-4 evaluate_0.5.5   gsubfn_0.6-5     gtable_0.1.2     httr_0.3        
 [7] labeling_0.2     lattice_0.20-29  MASS_7.3-33      munsell_0.4.2    parallel_3.0.2   plyr_1.8.1      
[13] proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.1      RCurl_1.95-4.1   reshape2_1.4     testthat_0.8.1   tools_3.0.2     
[19] whisker_0.3-2
```

Comment: Could you add `sessionInfo()` to your post?

Comment: You said "I've used them with no problems for many months now." - does that mean that the RStudio documentation links used to work with these packages? Can you pinpoint the time when the documentation links did stop working?

Comment: Yes - fairly recently. At some point over the past week. Could be due to the gui packages as that's what I've installed recently...